# Just bought a 2001 Jetta, the radio wiring is super screwed up... no clue what to do

Tags: vw, audio, wiring, jetta

It has a wiring harness in there but it’s not right, only one speaker works and there are several wires not attached to anything. And what is the blue and green connection? I’ve been trying to figure out but I can’t find much information on this stuff. All the colors seem to be different than the diagrams I’ve seen, which makes things harder. [image]

Comment: A good place to start would be to remove anything aftermarket and start over. Be prepared to take apart the dash and trace wires unless you can get an answer from the previous owner. You should also take better pictures of the connectors from the back side and find out if the car had a factory amp or not.

Comment: Does this have Bose speakers?

Comment: This really looks like someone had some aftermarket components in the car, as I see RCA plugs that normally would not feature in a car dash. I fear you may have to trace the wires manually, or take it a competent auto electrician to have things sorted out.

Answer (score 4):

Had to do this for customers before : start by removing all the non-original stuff.

Then with the key off use a meter and find the permanent live, next key to aux and find switched live, the ground or earth is usually brown - check by looking at the cigar lighter.

How many speakers? Then there will be that many pairs of wires - usually recognisable as a base colour and a trace colour(s) which match. If this is still not clear then take the door covers off and look on the speakers.

As length will be an issue, as each wire is identified I would extend it (30cm gives plenty of options and can always be cut down...) by soldering and insulating with heat shrink (those crimp connectors take up a lot of space and form an inflexible lump) and labelling each one.

Comment: Great advice and writeup ... should be pretty easy for anyone to follow in the same situation. +1